# Список последних комментариев из определенной рубрики?

Tags: wordpress

Есть код вывода последних комментариев. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать в этом коде вывод последних комментариев только из конкретной рубрики. И как вывести возле названия поста общее кол-во комментариев в записи?

```
$comment_len = 140;
    $comments = get_comments('status=approve&number=15');
    if ($comments) {
        foreach ($comments as $comment) {
            ?>
            <li>
               <?php echo get_avatar($comment,$size='50' ); ?>
                <?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?>
        <?php
                  $d = "j F Y в H:i";
                  $comment_ID = $comment->comment_ID;
                  $comment_date = get_comment_date( $d, $comment_ID );
                  echo $comment_date;
                  ?>

               <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . '#comment-' . $comment->comment_ID; ?>"><?php echo mb_substr( strip_tags( $comment->comment_content ), 0, 75 ); ?>...</a>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID); ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        echo "<li>Комментарии отсутствуют</li>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте такой код:

```
$cats        = array( 'uncategorized' );
$my_comments = get_comments( 'status=approve&number=15' );

if ( $my_comments ) {
    foreach ( $my_comments as $my_comment ) {
        if ( in_category( $cats, $my_comment->comment_post_ID ) ) {
            ?>
            <li>
                <?php
                echo get_avatar( $my_comment, $size = '50' );
                echo esc_html( $my_comment->comment_author );
                $d            = 'j F Y в H:i';
                $comment_date = get_comment_date( $d, $my_comment->comment_ID );
                echo esc_html( $comment_date );
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $my_comment->comment_post_ID ) . '#comment-' . $my_comment->comment_ID ); ?>">
                    <?php echo esc_html( mb_substr( $my_comment->comment_content, 0, 75 ) ) . ' ... '; ?>
                </a>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $my_comment->comment_post_ID ) ); ?>">
                    <?php
                    echo get_the_title( $my_comment->comment_post_ID );
                    echo ' (' . intval( wp_count_comments( $my_comment->comment_post_ID )->total_comments ) . ')';
                    ?>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
    }
} else {
    echo '<li>Комментарии отсутствуют</li>';
}
```

В массиве `$cats` укажите названия категорий, по которым делать вывод комментариев.

`in_category()` фильтрует комментарии по категориям.

`wp_count_comments()` выводит кол-во комментариев данного поста.

Comment: При использовании кода получаю 500 ошибку :( Если просто использовать wp_count_comments(), то выдает неправильное кол-во комментариев к посту - у всех записей по 1, хотя там другие значения :(

Comment: В какой строке и какую именно? Включите wp_debug https://wp-kama.ru/id_7791/debag-v-wordpress-wp_debug.html

Comment: А с чего вы решили "просто использовать" `wp_count_comments()`?Почитайте описание функции.

Comment: Дебаг не показывает ошибку. Единственное, что выдает - Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in *******/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1562. Но эта ошибка выдается и в оргигинальном коде, хотя ее и не видно без дебага.

Comment: Я имел в виду, что в вашем коде убрал категории и оставил wp_count_comments(), и так пробовал в целом код.

Comment: Вв испортили мой код и сетуете на 500. Вставьте его как есть. И покажите, в какой строке 500. Debug не дает ошибок - так не бывает.

Comment: Что значит испортил ваш код? Я вставил ваш код как есть и получаю 500 ошибку. Вы бы сами попробовали вставить и посмотреть, что происходит.

Comment: Да, действительно, была пропущена закрывающая скобка в `echo esc_html( $comment_date ;`. Вот поэтому я и просил вас включить xdebug и посмотреть в какой строке ошибка. Мне пришлось сделать эту элементарную отладку за вас. А почему я решил, что вы испортили код - потому что вы сами писали, что вносиил в него изменения: "Я имел в виду, что в вашем коде убрал категории и оставил wp_count_comments()". Вопрос в том, как вы это сделали.

Comment: В общем, код работает, я его поправил в ответе для примера с категорией uncategorized. Кроме исправления ошибки, привёл его в соответсвие со стандартами кодирования WordPress. Заменил переменные $comment и $comments на такие же с префиксом my_, потому что указанные переменные являются глобальными в WP, и изменять их в свойм коде нельзя. Точная копия кода сейчас в шаблоне страницы тестового сайта http://test.kagg.eu/so884284/  Посмотрите на результат.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь рубрики работают! Единственное, в этом коде так и не заработали правильно счетчики комментариев в записи - к любой записи всегда отображается 1 комментарий, хотя у записи, к примеру, 20 комметариев и т.д.

Comment: Поправил ответ. `wp_count_comments()` возвращает объект, из которого надо выбрать поле, например `->total_comments`

Comment: Теперь идеально! Еще раз огромное вам спасибо!